# Homoskedasticity: Plotting residuals against fitted values

Tags: regression, data-visualization, heteroscedasticity

Does the below graph show homoscedasticity?

[image]

Comment: The model looks wrong given the systematic curvature. That's more important than *scedasticity. To get advice on a better one, tell and show us more about the data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have heteroscedasticity and also maybe an omitted term from your regression since the mean of the residuals isn't always 0.